# Disable all the options except the default - ChoiceField Django Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

So basically here is what I am trying to do:

I would like to have a way to be able to make some of the fields readonly depending on the user.

So far it's easy but here comes the problem, I need to make some select input read only and well...they don't work well with read only. The thing is the user is still able to play with it even though the new value is not submitted. I want the select field to be disabled but if I do that, the value is not sent via the POST and there is a problem with the form valid method.

So after reading around, I understand that the only way is to disable all the fields except the one that is selected by default?

How is it possible

Here is what I have so far:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(TeamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)

    if instance and instance.pk is None:
        self.fields['division'].initial = 1

    user_role = self.user.memberaccount.get_role()

    if user_role != 'admin':
```

And here is whhere I want to disable the choices....

Thanks a lot for your help,
Ara

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible choices here:

- create a custom widget which will show the disabled select alongside a hidden input containing the value to submit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances
- set the field as required=False and create a clean_division() method inside your form to populate the field if it hasn't been submitted: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute